# Export manually edited htmlwidget to SVG or similar

Tags: r, d3.js, sankey-diagram, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I often create Sankey-diagrams in R via [{sankeyD3}](https://github.com/fbreitwieser/sankeyD3), because it seems to be the package with the most options/features to do so. However, one feature that is missing is the ability to set the order of nodes on the y-axis (although [this issue](https://github.com/fbreitwieser/sankeyD3/pull/16#issuecomment-1158832344) tried to fix that?).

Therefore, I must arrange the nodes manually afterwards. I can do this by setting `dragY = TRUE` when creating the diagram and then exporting it to an html file via `htmlwidgets::saveWidget()`. This allows me to manually drage the nodes when opening the html file.

## reprex

```r
# remotes::install_github("fbreitwieser/sankeyD3")
links <- data.frame(
  source = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4),
  target = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6),
  value = c(2, 3, 4, 2, 3 , 4, 4, 5)
)

nodes <- data.frame(
  label = c("A1", "B1", "B3", "B2", "C1", "D1", "D2"),
  yOrder = c(1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2)
)

out <- sankeyD3::sankeyNetwork(
  Links = links,
  Nodes = nodes,
  Source = "source",
  Target = "target",
  Value  = "value",
  NodeID = "label",
  fontFamily = "Arial",
  fontSize = 12,
  numberFormat = ",.1s",
  height = 500,
  width = 700,
  dragY = TRUE)

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(out,
                        file = here::here("out.html"),
                        selfcontained = TRUE)
```

and here is a screenshot showing the exported html on the left and the one where I manually rearranged the nodes on the right:
[image]

## Question

My goal is to insert the edited diagram into a word-document in the best possible quality. So I guess I want to know how to export the edited html-file to a SVG format or similar?

Comment: I've used webshot to save htmlWidgets as image files in the past. Not sure if it will do exactly what you want but it might be worth looking up.

Comment: You can get a PDF with the **webshot** package or the **webshot2** package.

Comment: For SVG there is **WebVector**: http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/webvector/

Comment: @moodymudskipper' as Stephane comments above, `webshot2` can output to pdf: `webshot2::webshot("out.html", "out.pdf")` (with caveats on browser requirements)

Comment: AFAICT the pdf output doesn't contain vector graphics so it doesn't work for me

Comment: ah okay.@moodymudskipper. For info, how do you tell ... the pdf looks okay under zoom to me

Comment: I don't know for sure tbh. It's what I understand from how webshot2 works, I didn't see the doc mention vector graphics.

Comment: yes, I thought chromium may have a facility for some fancy screenshot type stuff but couldn't see anything in the docs (and possibly wishing for a unicorn) . But the resulting pdf didnt get pixelated under 1000% zoom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a headless browser to do this - example below use [chromote](https://github.com/rstudio/chromote):

> Chromote is an R implementation of the Chrome DevTools Protocol. It
> works with Chrome, Chromium, Opera, Vivaldi, and other browsers based
> on Chromium. By default it uses Google Chrome (which must already be
> installed on the system). To use a different browser, see Specifying
> which browser to use.

So, if you have Chrome this will code will open the output of `saveWidget` and run it in a headless Chrome session. The steps are: create a new session; navigate to the `htmlWidgets::saveWidget` output; wait till the load event has fired (async); then identify the `svg` element and get the `outerHTML`; then persist this:

```
outFile <- 'C:\\Users\\robin\\Downloads\\out.html'
svg1File <- 'C:\\Users\\robin\\Downloads\\out1.svg'
svg2File <- 'C:\\Users\\robin\\Downloads\\out2.svg'

b <- chromote::ChromoteSession$new()
b$Page$navigate(outFile, wait_ = FALSE)
b$Page$loadEventFired(wait_ = FALSE)$
  then(function(value) {
    svgList <- b$Runtime$evaluate('document.querySelector("svg").outerHTML')
  })$
  then(function (value) {
    writeLines(value$result$value, svg1File)
  })
```

There is a little problem in this which you can see by double clicking on this `out1.svg` file and note it does not render the image. This is because the `xmlns` tag is missing from the `svg` element. You can add this with functions from the [`xml2`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xml2/index.html) package like so:

```
svg <- xml2::read_xml(svg1File)
root <- xml2::xml_find_first(svg, xpath = '//svg')
xml2::xml_set_attr(root, attr = 'xmlns', value = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
xml2::write_xml(svg, svg2File)
```

This adds the standard namespace attribute to the `svg` and this file will render in a browser. I have an old version of Word that does not import `svg` so cannot test that.

Full code based on yours:

```
outFile <- 'C:\\Users\\robin\\Downloads\\out.html'
svg1File <- 'C:\\Users\\robin\\Downloads\\out1.svg'
svg2File <- 'C:\\Users\\robin\\Downloads\\out2.svg'

links <- data.frame(
  source = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4),
  target = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6),
  value = c(2, 3, 4, 2, 3 , 4, 4, 5)
)

nodes <- data.frame(
  label = c("A1", "B1", "B3", "B2", "C1", "D1", "D2"),
  yOrder = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2)
)

out <- sankeyD3::sankeyNetwork(
  Links = links,
  Nodes = nodes,
  Source = "source",
  Target = "target",
  Value  = "value",
  NodeID = "label",
  fontFamily = "Arial",
  fontSize = 12,
  numberFormat = ",.1s",
  height = 500,
  width = 700,
  dragY = TRUE)


htmlwidgets::saveWidget(out,
                        file = outFile,
                        selfcontained = TRUE)

b <- chromote::ChromoteSession$new()
b$Page$navigate(outFile, wait_ = FALSE)
b$Page$loadEventFired(wait_ = FALSE)$
  then(function(value) {
    svgList <- b$Runtime$evaluate('document.querySelector("svg").outerHTML')
  })$
  then(function (value) {
    writeLines(value$result$value, svg1File)
  })

svg <- xml2::read_xml(svg1File)
root <- xml2::xml_find_first(svg, xpath = '//svg')
xml2::xml_set_attr(root, attr = 'xmlns', value = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
xml2::write_xml(svg, svg2File)
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good but unfortunately I can't reproduce this on macOS, I use tempfile() to create correct path at the start of the script, then I use `b$Page$navigate(paste0("file://", normalizePath(outFile)), wait_ = FALSE)` because the default macOS path seems not to be supported (It says the URL is invalid), but then it chokes on the next step, svg1File is not created

Comment: I could make it work by running separately `svgList <- b$Runtime$evaluate('document.querySelector("svg").outerHTML')` then `writeLines(svgList$result$value, svg1File)` instead of the chained `b$Page$loadEventFired(...)$...` call. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Open the result in a browser, make any manual adjustments you want, then use an SVG extractor like https://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/ to save it as an SVG.